# Any equivalent in bigquery to postgres any() array?

Tags: google-bigquery

Coming to BigQuery somewhat recently from Postgres - I'm used to utilizing the following pattern fairly regularly in specific cases, but not where the CTE set would be too big of course.

```
with cte1 as (
   select id from my_table where feature1 = x, feature2 = y
)
select id, detail1, detail2, detail3 from my_table
    where id = ANY( select id from cte1 )
```

Something to the effect of using my CTE as a place to gather records of a particular interest (something in common, something uncommon, outliers, dupes etc.) and then passing that to my main select using the `id = ANY( select id from CTE )` pattern.

What would be the equivalent in BigQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equivalent is

```
where id in ( select id from CTE )
```

So, your query can look like below

```
with cte1 as (
   select id from my_table where feature1 = x and feature2 = y
)
select id, detail1, detail2, detail3 from my_table
    where id in ( select id from cte1 )
```